# Extracting key value pair and transpose nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, data-manipulation

From this below data

```
people = {1: {'name': 'John', 'age': '27', 'sex': 'Male'},
          2: {'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'sex': 'Female'},
          3: {'name': 'Luna', 'age': '24', 'sex': 'Female'},
          4: {'name': 'Peter', 'age': '29', 'sex': 'Male'}}
```

1. How do I extract all the names: ex: ['John','Marie','Luna','Peter']
2. How do I transpose this dict and get something like below

   new_dict = {name: {'John','Marie','Luna','Peter'},
   age:{'27','22','24','29'},
   sex:{'Male','Female','Female','Male'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `dataframe` from your `dict` like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(people)
```

Transpose the `dataframe`

```
df2 = df.T
```

Convert the `dataframe` to `dict`

```
df2.to_dict
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using pandas dataframe as say I have a fourth column for each person which is scores: [50,60,70,80], so a multi dimensional array for each person

Comment: Can you edit your ques with this data too so that I can check, or you can check it by yourself through converting your dict to np.ndarray then transpose your np.ndarray.